# Flow “Required module not found” when importing a CSS file

Tags: flowtype

When I try to import CSS via webpack(import (./index.css)) I'm getting this error:

```
3: import './index.css';
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ./index.css. Required module not found
```

I have a structure like ComponentName→(index.js, index.css), so that each component has all dependencies inside.

I tried [this](https://gist.github.com/lambdahands/d19e0da96285b749f0ef) hack but it didn't work for me. Could I just ignore it somehow?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Add this to your flow config

```
[options]
module.name_mapper.extension='css' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/CSSModuleStub.js'
```

And add create a file to your root `CSSModuleStub.js`:

```
// @flow
type CSSModule = { [key: string]: string }
const emptyCSSModule: CSSModule = {}
export default emptyCSSModule
```

If you want clean path, you can adjust like this

```
[options]
module.name_mapper.extension='css' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow/stub/css-modules.js'
```

And so rename `CSSModuleStub.js` to `flow/stub/css-modules.js`.

---

While we are at it, if you need some others stubs (eg: for `url-loader`) here is another example

Create `flow/stub/url-loader.js`

```
// @flow
const s: string = ""
export default s
```

And add

```
module.name_mapper='.*\.\(svg\|png\|jpg\|gif\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow/stub/url-loader.js'
```

if you use `url-loader` for svg, png, jpg and gif. This will allow Flow to make the correct module replacement (url-loader returns a string (base64 or file-loader path).

For example if you do

```
import logoSVG from "./logo.png"
logoSVG.blah.stuff() // <-- flow will throw here
```

Flow will throw an error.

Comment: This is super useful, it would be great to have this referenced from the official docs.

Comment: Is there any way of handling this problem if no file extension is provided in the `import`/`require`?

Comment: @ctrlplusb, this is now in the official docs [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-module-name-mapper-regex-string)

Answer (score 1):

In order to not have to declare CSSModule for every project, I've published an npm package that does so:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-module-flow

https://github.com/ckknight/css-module-flow

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MoOx, this is great!! Any suggestions on a stub for webpack bundle loader?

I was thinking something like this...

```
module.name_mapper='^bundle?[a-zA-Z0-9$_]+$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow/stubs/bundle-loader.js.flow'

require('bundle?lazy&name=bundleName!path/to/file')
```

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with bundle-loader :/

Comment: What I'm doing for bundle-loader is: `module.name_mapper='bundle.*?\!\(.*\)'->'\1'`. The annoying part is that with other aliases that we have mapped, I may have to add another version with the bundler.