# How to flow type a 'require('')' image?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have an object that looks like this with a flow type. I checked what the `require` function is from hovering in Vscode. But not sure here to access it from? I'm wondering if I need something like [flow-typed](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed). But can't find it there. Am i typing this correctly?

```
// @flow
const backgroundImage = require('./myBg.jpeg')

type configType = {
  backgroundImage: string | NodeRequire
}

const config = {
  backgroundImage
}
```

Comment: not sure, and cannot find anything on that in their docs. for React Native typing is a number worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44065642/how-to-do-flow-type-annotation-for-react-native-resources?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 1):

If you are using webpack and url loader the image would typically be a string. You can use the `name_mapper.extension` [option of flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-module-name-mapper-extension-string-string) to automatically type all `jpeg` (and also other files if you extend the regex) file imports as strings:

```
# .flowconfig
[options]
module.name_mapper.extension='jpeg' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/ImageFlowStub.js.flow'
```

and then create `ImageFlowStub.js.flow` file in your project root (or really anywhere else and adjust the path in the `.flowconfig`:

```js
/* @flow */

declare export default string;
```

See also this question: [Flow “Required module not found” when importing a CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912675/)